# Scanner input skipping next input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am now having a difficult time fixing this problem.
So, I have this code snippet here which asks 3 input from the user.

```
 case 0:
      String accnum,pin,name;
      System.out.print("Enter account name: ");
      name = input.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
      accnum = input.next();
      System.out.print("Enter account PIN: ");
      pin = input.next();
      atm.set_accinfos(name,accnum,pin);
      //System.out.print(atm.return_acc() + "\t" + atm.return_pin() + "\n");
    break;
```

But everytime I run it, it always skips the input for the String "name", I tried using input.next();  on it and it works but then it will now skip the input for String "accnum".

EDIT: It also just happens if the input from "name" has a space on it, for example : John Doe.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: are you using this same scanner at all *before* this block of code?

Comment: @LukeWillis - Actually thats a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This. i think problem with next(). since next reads input as tokens with default delimiter(i think space is the default delimiter).:

```
case 0:
String accnum,pin,name;

System.out.print("Enter account name: ");
name = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
accnum = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter account PIN: ");
pin = input.nextLine();

atm.set_accinfos(name,accnum,pin);
//System.out.print(atm.return_acc() + "\t" + atm.return_pin() + "\n");
break;
```

Comment: also, I edited the orig post, the problem only exists if I entered a string with space on it on String "name"

Comment: yeah, it still skips it

Answer (score 1):

The `nextLine()` gobbles the newline character produced by the `next()` of account pin (when you hit enter). So, it won't ask for name. Add `input.nextLine()` after `pin = input.next();` and try

Comment: @ScratchFever - then use nextLine()` everywhere :P. The old answer  should work. Are you hitting enter after you type number and pin as well?. i.e, 2 times?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `input` anywhere before this block of code, then you need to be sure to call `nextLine` earlier on.

If you use `next` instead, then your input stream will still contain a new line character (`\n`). Thus, when you start this block of code with `nextLine`, that call will take the previous `\n` and not the name which was just entered.

In general, if your `Scanner` is reading `System.in`, then you should use `nextLine` everywhere. `next`, `nextInt`, and the other next methods are meant for more predictable data.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thats for the help everyone, I managed to fix it by adding "input.nextLine();" before "name = input.nextLine();"